# How to get and save Wordpress content (html, css, images, videos) from a Java program?

Tags: import, export

I apologize if it's not the good place to ask this question. Please if it's not help me to find where I have to ask it.

So here is my challenge. I need to get and save WordPress content (HTML, CSS, images and videos) from a Java program.

```
          HTML, images, CSS
WordPress -----------------> File system
```

Then I'd like to parse this content to integrate the pages into my existing Spring web application. For example it means that

```
http://localhost/wp-content/image1.png
```

will need to change into

```
http://localhost/spring/image1.png
```

to worked into my Spring application.

I've thought about many possibilities so far. I would like to get your feedback and may be suggest other solutions that I didn't think about.

1. Use this little [Java wget](https://github.com/axet/wget) program, to get all the content from the WordPress site and then save it.
   **Pros** : It is sure it will work as its wget's goal to create site mirrors.
   **Cons** : Links won't work in my Spring application and I will need to parse the html and css codes anyway.
2. Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).
   **Pros** : As its a parser I can directly change the URL to integrate it in my Spring application.
   **Cons** : Can't be sure it is possible to save the content on the hard drive.
3. Use a WordPress plugin to export pages.
   **Pros** : Only pages related to the current change are resaved on the hard drive (it's possible to specify a folder).
   **Cons** : It's not in Java (I can't maintain the plugin). Anyway I need to watch the destination folder and each time a file change I need to reparse it to change the links to make it work in my spring application.

I didn't find other solutions and all those solutions are pretty bad. Do you think about other ways to do that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my own question. Jsoup can do what I need:

1. Extract the content (tested)
2. Change the link for Spring (tested)
3. Save HTML (tested), images (tested), videos (not yet tested)